# Electric force of Electron between Proton and Electron

Tags: electricity

This is a really basic question and I don't want to annoy anyone with it, but I gotta ask: is my consideration right? According to the image $\vec{F}_G$ (total Force) should be $2\cdot F_e$. I'm still not sure - especially about $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$: Is this just a vector divided by its magnitude?

[image]

I've created this image, so might come with plenty of errors within it

Comment: $\vec{r} / r = \hat{r}$ is a unit vector (magnitude 1 vector) in the direction of $\vec{r}$. You're exactly right that the force on the middle electron due to the two adjacent charges is in the left direction and twice the magnitude of one of the forces ($F_e$). The only thing I would point out is that it would make more sense to show vectors with arrows to show what the direction of the vectors is.

Comment: okay, intuitively that makes sense to me. In contrast to our reflections, I've read multiple times that the electric field in the middle of 2 equally charges has to be 0. How can this be in accordance with the doubled force acting on the electron? I also do not really understand why the unit vector is once negative and then positive. It was just an assumption.

Comment: The electric field in the middle of two equally chared objects (for example, two electrons with charge $-e$) is indeed zero. You can think of this like there is some equal attraction on a positive charge in the middle in both directions, so it cancels each other out. However, in this situation, there is repulsion from the right charge (like charges repel) and attraction towards the left charge (opposite charges attract). The magnitude of the charge ($e$) is the same in both cases, but the direction is opposite due to the sign of the charge.

Comment: I would suggest to draw a coordinate system and draw forces as arrows to indicate direction, and also to think about whether you expect charges to attract or repel each other to check whether your answer makes sense. (like charges repel, opposite charges attract). The unit vector will be negative to the left and positive to the right if you define the center charge as being at the origin of your coordinate system.